# Getting only integer from string in php:can't get the float values correctly

Tags: php, string

I am trying to get only integer from string for these i am using `filter_var` in php

Here is my code

```
$str="Your base price is 456";
echo filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

But if the string contains  a floating point value `filter_var` returns  integer without the floating point value.

```
Eg; 
$str="Your base price is 45.57";
echo filter_var(currencyConvert($currency,$results[0]->base_price),FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

this will echo integer as `4557` but i need the value as same as the string.

ie  it should be `45.57` but i will get it as `4557`

Is any way to get this as correct float value?

Comment: What exactly is your objective? Do you want to print it as a floating point value? Or an integer?

Comment: Print as a floating point value

Comment: Have you tried `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT`? Generally, it is not advisable to use INT functions on non-integers, and this is one of many such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` but you must use the correct flag ie  `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION`

```
$str="Your base price is 45.57";
echo filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
print_r("\n");
echo filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
print_r("\n");
```

This prints

```
4557
45.57
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "Your base price is 456";
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", '', $str);  // Prints 456
echo "<br/>";
$str = "Your base price is 45.57";
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", '', $str);  // Prints 45.57
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

`echo filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

you have used `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` to get integer number form a string. To get float number from a string you can use `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`. For more information check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_float.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will help you.

```
$str="Your base price is 45.6";
preg_match_all('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $str, $matches);
$floats = array_map('floatval', $matches[0]);
print_r($floats);
```

Or

```
echo filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

Comment: Use any above code it will surly solved your problem. @Blessan Kurien

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$str = "Your base price is 45.57";
$float_val=(float) filter_var( $str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ) ;
echo $float_val;
```